# How to obtain reference to set created inside of loop?

Tags: java, set

```
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < width - 1; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < height - 1; j++)
        {
            new HashSet();
            count++;
        }
    }
```

I'm creating sets inside of two for loops, but how do I obtain reference to the sets? How would I be able to call "set1" or  "set2" for example?

Comment: Put them in some collection.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to put them in an `Arraylist`.

```
int count = 0;
List<Set<YourClass>> arr = new ArrayList<Set<YourClass>>();
for (int i = 0; i < width - 1; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < height - 1; j++)
    {
        Set s = new HashSet<YourClass>();
        arr.add(s);
        count++;
    }
}
```

Then you can call whichever one you want:

```
Set theFirstSet = arr.get(0);
```

And do things with them:

```
theFirstSet.add(your_class_instance);
```

Comment: I know the OP uses them in their example, you really shouldn't use raw types.

Comment: No problem. I +1 you.

Answer (score 0):

The sets need a name e.g.

```
HashSet set1;
```

make them fields at class level so can refer anywhere.

```
set1 = new HashSet();
```

Comment: the OP is creating multiple Sets, not just one

Comment: Agreed.  I was just trying to push the names up to fields so they could be referenced outside the loops.